# Convert date and time from UTC to IST and vice versa in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a project which saves the time in `UTC` zone. I want to display the time in `Asia/Kolkata` zone in the front end.

```
$createdAt = '2017-03-16 23:21:56'; 

/* The indian time was 2017-03-17 11:52 when the record was placed, so after converting it to Asia/Kolkata it should display 2017-03-17 11:52 (seconds does not matter) */
```

> My PHP code to convert it into Asia/Kolkata

```
$createdAt = '2017-03-16 23:21:56';
$dateFrom = new DateTime($createdAt, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$dateFrom->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$IST = $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The output is `2017-03-17 09:51:56` instead of `2017-03-17 11:52:56` . The output shows 2 hours before the actual time. I can't figure it out.

Your suggestions will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your input date/time is in the [Chicago time zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/chicago), then one should take into account the DST. The change occurred on 12th March 02:00 local time so your input (assuming `$createdAt` is correct) is already in DST regime (i.e., UTC -05:00).

Since Kolkata is UTC+05:30 (and there is no DST adjustment), the total difference for your particular input is 10:30 which justifies the output of `2017-03-17 09:51:56`.

Comment: Okay understood, so you mean there is no way to convert a time from one timezone into another accurately without compromising a minute ..??
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @SantanuBiswas so you want to round it to the nearest minute or strip the seconds?